# Finding similar patterns in text using Python 3.7

Tags: python, regex

I have a collection of text patterns (keywords) and my goal is to find similar and proper words in a HTML text and collect them to a list using python 3.7. For example, if my given set of patterns is: {"banana", "my-apple", "(orange)", "big grapes"} I would like to find words in the HTML text such as: "banana", "my-apple", "my apple", "(orange)", "big-grapes", "big grapes", ">banana" and so on. What is the best way to do that? I thought about using the regex library but couldn't exactly to find the words as I wish.

My current code is:

```
import re

def find_patterns_in_text(keywords, html_text):
   output_list = []
      for keyword in keywords:
         if re.findall(keyword, html_text):
            output_list.append(keyword)
   return output_list
```

My code doesn't work well because it can't find the following cases:

- if the word in the HTML text or in the keywords set appear with some kind of a special char beside it, it doesn't recognize it.
- if one of the keywords contains "-" instead of " " or in a similar way " " instead of "-" and in the HTML text the same word appears but the " " and "-" are not suitable, it doesn't recognize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the patterns you search for and replace `-` and spaces with a `[\s-]+` pattern inside the resulting expression.

[Python code](https://tio.run/##dZHBboMwEETv/ootF2wFuPQWtYrUWw/9goAQgQWsgm2tjVK@ntpOiNJDzWW0nn0zyGZ1o1av2yZno8kBIWMd9tBL1dWmcQ5J2Vqq2uGP49@4XjV1NoPRzVOciSMDAL04s7h6ktbBO5yrMOs1wX0BpNqljf5wZO/TCosNtSOnhJ/eXsqrSOAQx8uFU8pPx7I8Q16JQ5oBpeeytHkVNRZo28bg3kmIsOgpEfJUMHo/xSMW/tYtGmNQdQ9MsBG6hdSzizF/b8OvJZdG@c8nJPOa@@UJg@aaGjVgSE4ucoCBfDcbXdjJViq83WiH7aj0pIc1qZh1JNXgsemDukODgrva4Rl4dH5Dex1XMvi6BxTw8Yxf15QZj3f837f0kFsDIbbtFw):

```py
import re

def find_patterns_in_text(keywords, html_text):
   output_list = []
   for keyword in keywords:
       if re.search(r"(?<!\w)" + re.sub(r'(?:\\[ -])+', r'[\\s-]+', re.escape(keyword)) + r"(?!\w)", html_text, re.I):
           output_list.append(keyword)
   return output_list

keys = ["banana", "my-apple", "(orange)", "big grapes", "medicine", "biotechnology"]
string = 'banana", my-apple, my apple, (orange), big-grapes, banana, Medicine. Biotechnologyyy'
print(find_patterns_in_text(keys, string))
```

Result: `['banana', 'my-apple', '(orange)', 'big grapes', 'medicine']`.

The `re.search(re.sub(r'(?:\\[ -])+', r'[\\s-]+', re.escape(keyword)), html_text, re.I)` piece of code does most of the job. `re.escape(keyword)` prepends special characters with a backslash so that `(` could match a literal parenthesis, etc. As the string is already escaped, all spaces and hyphens are prepended with a backslash and hence `re.sub(r'(?:\\[ -])+', r'[\\s-]+', ...)` is used to replace all sequences of one or more backslash + a space or hyphen with a `[\s-]+` pattern. It will match whitespace or hyphen in the subsequent call to `re.search`. Due to `(?<!\w)` prefix and `(?!\w)` suffix, the keyword matched must be a whole word. `re.search(..., html_text, re.I)` performs a partial case insensitive regex search against the entire string.

Comment: It doesn't work well, even if the same word appears both in keywords and the text it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: for example if the keywords is: ["medicine"] and the HTML text is: "Medicine." or another example: keywords is: ["biotechnology"]  and text is: <a href="/wiki/Biotechnology_risk" title="Biotechnology risk">Biotechnology risk</a>

Comment: @AviFerdman If the search must be case insensitive use `re.I`. `re.search(re.sub(r'(?:\\[ -])+', r'[\\s-]+', re.escape(keyword)), html_text, re.I)`. See [this Python code](https://tio.run/##dVHLboMwELzzFStfwCqQQ29Rkkq99dAvCAg5sIAVYlv2opSvpzYJUaKq9mW089ixbCbqtXqfZ3kx2hJYjKIGW2ilaiojiNAqV0lVEf5Qcsbpqm3jUujpMiwzvo0AQI9kRqoG6Qj2cCzDrNUW7gaQaoVu0YcjW78tdyhs3ScBjafExsnHtiiOkJX8LU7BxseicFm5YMzR1cLgWoPzpx4L/8Uf6fDaKhfGoGoe1iCzSKNVz6oo8rwLL2AnofxlKbDLlHnzgAEn2grVIQ/4JDvorO/jFhU2spYKb4wmrHulB91NrIwcWak6Hxs/UtfQgOCO1vAUfHR2i/Z4saTwfV@Qw05Ab7Hds81VnuXm83lbZaU7MyBJA@7ZCwULdfg7223EAeLI@JKU/PvxvsrtHZzP8y8).

Comment: I converted both the text and the keywords to lower cases because I can only use default libraries, however It still doesn't recognize the pattern.

Comment: @AviFerdman  [Check the link](https://tio.run/##dVHLboMwELzzFStfwCqQQ29Rkkq99dAvCAg5sIAVYlv2opSvpzYJUaKq9mW089ixbCbqtXqfZ3kx2hJYjKIGW2ilaiojiNAqV0lVEf5Qcsbpqm3jUujpMiwzvo0AQI9kRqoG6Qj2cCzDrNUW7gaQaoVu0YcjW78tdyhs3ScBjafExsnHtiiOkJX8LU7BxseicFm5YMzR1cLgWoPzpx4L/8Uf6fDaKhfGoGoe1iCzSKNVz6oo8rwLL2AnofxlKbDLlHnzgAEn2grVIQ/4JDvorO/jFhU2spYKb4wmrHulB91NrIwcWak6Hxs/UtfQgOCO1vAUfHR2i/Z4saTwfV@Qw05Ab7Hds81VnuXm83lbZaU7MyBJA@7ZCwULdfg7223EAeLI@JKU/PvxvsrtHZzP8y8), it works. No need to convert to lower case.

Comment: Correct! Works great! I'll be glad if you could explain a bit more about the 'sub' function and the parameters you used for it.

Comment: It worked great but now I see that it also recognize cases that I'm not interested in, the problematic case is if the keyword is a substring of other proper string. for example: keyword = ["biotechnology"] and text = ""biotechnologyyyy"" I want the output to be an empty list, however in this case the output is: ["biotechnology"]